# Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null

Tags: java, persistence, java-ee-6

I try to use JSPs by creating a simple Eclipse dynamic web project.

I made a basic JSP and a form that creates a parameterized request to a HttpServlet. This servlet should just use a entity bean to store the data into a database.

I used mapping via annotations.

This is the invoking part of my jsp:

```
<form action="persistencedemo" method="get">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value='ok'/>
    <input type="hidden" name="firstName" value='<jsp:getProperty property="firstname" name="newCustomer"/>' />
    <input type="hidden" name="lastName"  value='<jsp:getProperty property="lastname" name="newCustomer"/>' />  
</form>
```

... this is the main section of my bean:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="CUSTOMERS")
public class CustomerBean implements Serializable {

@Id
@Column(name = "CUSTOMER_ID")
private Long id;

@Column(name = "FIRST_NAME")
private String firstname;

@Column(name = "LAST_NAME")
private String lastname;

public CustomerBean() {
    this.firstname = "";
    this.lastname = "";
}

    // Getters & Setters
```

and now - finally - this is my very simple servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name="PersistenceDemo", urlPatterns = {"/persistencedemo"})
public class PersistenceDemo extends HttpServlet {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @PersistenceUnit
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;
    @Resource
    private UserTransaction userTransaction;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp)
            throws ServletException, IOException {


        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        CustomerBean c1 = new CustomerBean();
        CustomerBean c2 = new CustomerBean();

        c1.setFirstname("My");
        c1.setLastname("Self");
        c1.setId(3L);

        c2.setId(4L);
        c2.setFirstname(req.getParameter("firstName"));
        c2.setLastname(req.getParameter("lastName"));

        try {
            userTransaction.begin();
            em.persist(c1);
            em.persist(c2);
            userTransaction.commit();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        resp.getWriter().print("Updated database!");

    }
}
```

[Update]
My persistence.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<persistence xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence">
    <persistence-unit name="hello-world" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <class>com.jpa.PersistenceDemo</class>  
        <properties>

            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/customerdb" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="customeruser" />
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="customerpass" />
      </properties>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**Problem**: I linked the mySQL connector and created the tables, but all the time when I am invoking the *entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()* it crashes with the error message:

```
Unable to retrieve EntityManagerFactory for unitName null
```

Well, aside from the fact that I should probably use another structure to separate model (bean) from view (jsp):

What is the problem here?

Comment: were is entityManagerFactory initialized?

Comment: Include your persistence.xml file to the question.

Comment: post the content of persistence.xml and I also think you should specify the unit name of @PersistenceUnit.

Comment: I forgot to write a persistence.xml. I added a simple persistence.xml in my project which is now undeployable cause of "java.net.ConnectException: error while connecting on localhost port 1527". But I set it to 3306? Complex stuff ...

Comment: Why are you listing your demo class in persistence.xml? It should only point to entities - and this is also superfluous, since they will automatically be found via their annotations. --- A little off-topic recommendation: Since you posted this question under JEE6, don't use JSPs any more, go with Facelets as view technology.

Answer (score 0):

1. Where is your persistence.xml file located?
2. Maybe the project has incorrect structure? Is EJB in its own separate part? Try packing the parts of the project [using CDI](http://www.hascode.com/2011/02/creating-a-sample-java-ee-6-blog-application-with-jpa-ejb-cdi-jsf-and-primefaces-on-glassfish/) or into [Enterprise Application](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=32wpTh1TmY4).

Try creating a "New Enterprise Project" in whatever program in which you write Java and see what is automatically generated if you're unsure of what I'm talking about.

Comment: [Reference this picture](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/figures/overview-applicationModule.gif)